# Join two tables and with sum and fitering

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two tables `Users` and `Inputs` with the following schema

```
Users - id, name, create_time
Inputs - id, user_id, create_time, amount
```

I've created 2 similar queries that select join data from the two tables.

The first query returns all users, adding a field called `daily_amount` which sums all the `Inputs` of each user in a given time range - Works fine

The second query - **Adds a user id filter**

I want to limit the query to a specific user by Id (id = 12 in the given query), im getting inconsistent results, I get a single record, but it has a different `Id` and the `daily_amount` is incorrect.

Your assistance is appreciated.

```
-- All users query - Works fine
SELECT Users.id,
       Users.name,
       Users.create_time,
       SUM(Inputs.amount) AS daily_amount
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Inputs ON Users.id = Inputs.user_id
AND Inputs.create_time BETWEEN startTime AND endTime
GROUP BY Users.id,
         Users.name



-- User specific query
SELECT Users.id,
       Users.name,
       Users.create_time,
       SUM(Inputs.amount) AS daily_amount
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Inputs ON Users.id = Inputs.user_id
AND Users.id = 12             -- trying to filter only specific user by id
AND Inputs.create_time BETWEEN startTime AND endTime
GROUP BY Users.id,
         Users.name
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `user.id = 12` with `inputs.user_id = 12`?  Maybe just use a `where` clause after you've joined on the join-specific `id` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the condition in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT Users.id,
       Users.name,
       Users.create_time,
       SUM(Inputs.amount) AS daily_amount
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Inputs ON Users.id = Inputs.user_id
WHERE Users.id = 12
AND Inputs.create_time BETWEEN startTime AND endTime
GROUP BY Users.id, Users.name, Users.create_time
```

Comment: something is wrong with that query, the Android SQLite engine cant really parse it, I will try to get the exact error

Comment: Corrected, the left join was after the WHERE clause

Comment: I think you must do the same in your 1st query. Replace `AND Inputs.create_time BETWEEN startTime AND endTime` with `WHERE Inputs.create_time BETWEEN startTime AND endTime` even if it is giving you the right results, because these conditions are meant to be dealt in a WHERE clause.